# Show data from database with categories

Tags: php, mysql

I added a loop that uses link (row from table) to display all links in iframes like this :

```
require('connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM iframe ORDER BY date DESC");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
  echo '<b>Message if database is empty...</b>';
}
else
{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
           echo '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.website.com/'.$row['link']. '"></iframe>';
      }

}
```

Now I added categories, so when you upload link you select 1 of 3 options because of 3 different websites (with id 1,2,3). I want for all links with id=1 to have something like this:

```
echo '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.website.com/blabla/'.$row['link']. '" (//link that has id=1)></iframe>';
```

I would like that also for other two id's, I want all websites to be displayed, but I because of different urls I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply by comparing the id.
Example:

```
if ($row['id'] == 1) {
    echo '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.website.com/blabla/'.$row['link'].'"></iframe>';
}
```